# sorting data to provide top entries

Tags: r, sorting

I have a table like below. Each row has store id, discount % for one of their coupons. Each store could have multiple coupons but (store+discount %) is a primary key. I would like to find out top 10 coupons (by decreasing order of discount %) but would like to get only 2 coupon from the same store. What is the most efficient way to do this? My logic involves sorting data multiple times. Is there a better and more efficient way? I would like to do this in R.

Sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(Store=c("Lowes","Lowes","Lowes","Lowes","HD","HD","HD","ACE",
                         "ACE","Misc","Misc","Other","Other","Last","Last","Last"),
                 `discount_%`=c("60%","50%","40%","30%","60%","50%","40%","30%",
                                "20%","50%","30%","20%","10%","10%","5%","3%"),
                 check.names = FALSE)
```

1. my solution is ignore the store and sort the table by discount then
   create a ID. ID would represent coupons in descending order
2. Then by Store and discount create ID2 which would have rankings of
   coupons by store.
3. then filter all rows where ID2>2
4. then sort table by ID
5. take top 10 rows

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
df$`discount_%` <- as.numeric(gsub("%","",df$`discount_%`))

require(data.table)
setDT(df)[order(-`discount_%`),.SD[1:2],by=Store][order(-`discount_%`)[1:10],]
```

Output:

```
    Store discount_%
 1: Lowes         60
 2:    HD         60
 3: Lowes         50
 4:    HD         50
 5:  Misc         50
 6:  Misc         30
 7:   ACE         30
 8:   ACE         20
 9: Other         20
10: Other         10
```

Data is easier to work with in R without special characters, but if you need to add the percent sign back, try something like this:

```
paste0(df$`discount_%`,"%")
```

Comment: it works...what is your logic? Is there a better logic than what i have mentioned?

Comment: @user2543622 - I also just added some extra lines to the sample data to make the solution more error-proof. Basically this takes a max of two top discount values from each store, then it orders the output by the numeric value of the discount, limiting the total number of discounts listed to 10.

Comment: thanks for your efforts. But what is the best logic to solve this problem using less computing power. I appreciate your code, but would like to know the best logic - assume that we have billions of rows. what would be the most efficient way to solve this problem

Comment: @user2543622 - If working with billions of rows, you definitely won't want special characters in columns (e.g. $ or %). Those take up unnecessary space. For processing speed, the best methods I know of come from the data table package. In terms of the best logic, it really depends on exactly what you want your output to be. If you want the following conditions: (1) top 10 values, (2) no stores with more than 2 values, (3) sorted decreasing, then that's a complex task for a dataset that large. The given solution is about as efficient as possible. The logic you outlined in the OP will be slower.